# Lumen sending mails with GMail SMTP

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp

I have a Lumen app with a artisan task that sends an email.
Locally it works great with a mailtrap.io test environment.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=username
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

When I deploy my app I want to send emails with the GMail SMTP but it doesn't work. I get the following error:

> [Swift_TransportException]
>   Expected response code 220 but got code
>   "", with message ""

Here's my .env setup:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail

MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=email@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

I've searched a lot here on stackoverflow the past hours and tried everything but I can't get it to work, unfortunately.

Am I retarded or missing something?

Anyone can help me out? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the Gmail-Account have 2-Step-Verification enabled? If so, you might need to set an app password https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

Comment: @macghriogair I've tried that, doesn't work either :/

Comment: Have you tried using port 587?

Comment: @sunomad Yes, I have tried every combination.

Comment: tls instead of ssl?

Comment: @macghriogair Yes tried that too. Nothing seems to be working, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure the Google Account you're sending from has the settings to [allow less secure applications.](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)

Then try these settings in your .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=email@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```